# How to use var inside awk printf

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Hi I have something like this in my bash script

```
gawk '{ printf "%s %s", $1, $2 }' test.txt
```

Normaly I can limit the lenght of the strings with a number before the `s` like this:

```
# Limit strings to 10 characters
gawk '{ printf "%10s %10s", $1, $2 }' test.txt
```

How I can use a var for that limit ? I get the width of the current terminal with `tput cols` and I want to set dinamically the lenght of the strings.

Comment: The awk manual is online. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers and scroll down to `The C library printf’s dynamic width and prec capability (e.g., "%*.*s") is supported....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `*` in the format specifier to get the width from an argument to `printf`:

```
$ gawk -v width=10 '{ printf "%*s %*s\n", width, $1, width, $2 }' <<<"a b"                 
         a          b
$ gawk -v width=3 '{ printf "%*s %*s\n", width, $1, width, $2 }' <<<"a b"
  a   b
```

This also works with the precision argument (The number after a `.` in the format).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to break up your format string and insert the variable.

```sh
awk -v w=10 '{printf "%."w"f %."w"f", $1, $2}' <<< '1.2 3.5'
1.2000000000 3.5000000000

awk -v w=3 '{printf "%."w"f %."w"f", $1, $2}' <<< '1.2 3.5'
1.200 3.500
```